# Download image from Firebase with SDWebImage - Swift Error "Unexpected non-void return value in void function"

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, sdwebimage

I'm a beginner in Swift and I'm trying to create a function which returns an Animated Image thanks to SDWebImage.
The path of the Image is known and stored in Firestore in an array.
So the function input is the path of the image (or name), then it downloads the URL and put into an AnimatedImage.
The issue is there is an error in XCODE "Unexpected non-void return value in void function"

There is my function :

```
func getURL(path: String) -> AnimatedImage {
  
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    storage.reference().child(path).downloadURL(completion: { url, error in
        guard let url = url, error == nil else {
            return
        }
        
        let animatedImage = AnimatedImage(url: url)
        return animatedImage
    })
}
```

Does anyone know why i get this error ?
Thanks in advance for help
Jean

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here is that while your outer method `getURL(path: String) -> AnimatedImage` returns an image, the method `downloadURL()` is actually called asynchronously and doesn't return anything – so returning `animatedImage` here won't work.

Indeed, your method shouldn't return anything, because there won't be anything *to* return. Instead, your method should use a `completion` closure to provide the image:

```
func getURL(path: String, completion: ((AnimatedImage? -> Void))) {
    // Get your image...

    completion(animatedImage)  // Do this instead of returning
}
```

Then the caller gets access to the returned image via the completion closure provided:

```
getURL(path: imagePath, completion: { image in
    // `image` may (or may not be) your animated image
})
```

Comment: Ok got it !  Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

The issue relates to asynchronous (takes a while to complete, some code runs later with the results) and synchronous functions (control flow returns immediately).  To illustrate this:

```
func getURL(path: String) -> AnimatedImage {

    let storage = Storage.storage()
    
    // A - we arrive here first and we just 
    // call downloadURL, passing a block of code called a "completion handler" as an argument representing what to do later when the data comes back
    //
    storage.reference().child(path).downloadURL(completion: { url, error in
        /// C - Third: this block is (possibly) called, much later, when download is done
        // any return statement here is returning *from the completion block*
    })

    // B - we hit this line second
    // a return statement here or a closing } will return from the getURL function 
    // so we're about to return from the getURL function now...
}
```